# How to build an android Push Notification server in PHP

Tags: php, android, json, zend-framework, push-notification

I am developing an application and in that application I need to implement push notification.

Can anyone suggest me how to do develop the server in PHP (Json, Zend Framework if possible) and provide me a good tutorial on push notification?

Comment: maybe checkout https://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html

Comment: Welcome, Houx. You should research this topic (plenty of web searching) and add what you've found into your question. It's probably too broad a question to ask here though - see the FAQ.

Comment: I'm a new in this stuff, i did see that link and it didn't help me very much i need to have a clear tutorial to understand the concept. and thank Halfer

Comment: i did find some cool tutorial, hope it will help some one else.

http://developpeur.orange.tn/developper-ensemble/tutoriels/tutoriels/c2dm-android-cloud-to-device-messaging
http://www.mti.epita.fr/blogs/2012/01/27/c2dm/
http://blog.octo.com/notifications-push-android-c2dm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you want to send message to an android device your Server contacts -> Google Server Contacts -> android device .

So you integrate your ZF application with google c2d api . Here you can find one such implementation of this type of integration with ZF 
http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2010/11/21/android-c2dm-with-php-and-zend-framework/

Comment: on Stackoverflow we generally say thanks by accepting the answer :)

Comment: I'm new here, so i don't know very much about the rules

Comment: it's blur for me i didn't understand any think of i really suck at this. can any body else give me a video tutorial to do it.

Comment: @houx check this out http://www.slideshare.net/mwillbanks/minne-demopushnotifications

Answer (score 8):

["Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) is deprecated"](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/c2dm.html). Its new version is **Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)**. There is plenty of information and source code examples on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html).

Here is another useful post for [Android Push Notifications](http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/).